# What is gigabit in networking?

Tags: networking, gigabit-ethernet

What exactly is gigabit and do I really need it? Here are some points in which I would like to know:

- What is a gigabit router?
- What is gigabit Ethernet?
- What is gigabit Internet?

Comment: The question does not show research efforts. A Google search would have given you the answer.

Comment: A bit confusing for me since there aren't any videos to back it up

Comment: @MichaelBrakutt - Why do you require a video in order to believe information?

Answer (score 4):

Gigabit network is a network that run at speeds of 1Gigabit per second (or 1000 MegaBits). Ethernet are the lines in a network and your ethernet card in your PC.

Typical Ethernet is 100Mbit/s. Typical internet connections range between 12.5 to 60Mbit/s. Some of the more expensive stuff goes up to 125Mbit. If you don't have one of the faster lines and you're not doing anything on your network beyond using the internet, you don't need a Gigabit network. Now if you have access to Gigabit internet (1000Mbit/s) and can afford it, you will also need a Gbit ethernet card for your PC (comes in most motherboards these days), a Gbit router and you may or may not need to change the wiring - otherwise there's no point to getting it.

Now if you're doing stuff on your network that needs high bandwidth, then a 1 Gbit network may make sense for you.

A few examples of things that need high bandwidth on a network that would not be related to the internet: you have a high powered desktop with 2 powerful graphics cards and you're streaming games on Steam to your less powerful portable or a steam link in the living room. You're streaming 4k movies from your PC to your TV. You're in a team of video editors and are sharing video editing projects back and forth.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabit_Ethernet):

> In computer networking, **Gigabit Ethernet** (**GbE** or **1 GigE**) is a term describing various technologies for transmitting Ethernet frames at a rate of a gigabit per second (1,000,000,000 bits per second), as defined by the IEEE 802.3-2008 standard.

In addition, a Gigabit Router is a router that features a built-in switch that is capable of Gigabit Ethernet speeds.

I've personally never heard of "Gigabit Internet". Probably, it is a made-up term intended to mean an Internet connection with the speed at a factor of gigabytes per second.

**Note:** Gigabit must not be confused with gigabyte.